# Find a greedy algorithm to balance success rate and cost

Tags: algorithm, greedy

[image]

Hi! I'm trying to solve a problem like this. A task contains more than one alternative nodes. They will be executed in parallel. Every node has a success rate and a cost. The success rate can be increase by executing this task on multiply devices (The success rate that at least one device gets the result will increase by 1-(1-S)^N).

The goal of the task is to get result from any of these nodes. Once one node is successfully executed, others will stop. The problem is, how to define an algorithm that satisfy the overall success rate threshold that at least one node succeed and has the lowest cost.

I think this should be a greedy algorithm with 3 variables: number of devices, success rate and cost. I don't know how to compare the ratio of success rate and the cost. Can anyone help me please? We can assume the threshold of overall success rate is 90%.

Comment: You can just solve for `N` which gives `N = ceil(log(1-T) / log(1-S))` where `T` is the target success rate, e.g. `0.9` for 90%. So for choice 1 `N=9` and for choice 2 `N=5`.

Comment: @user3386109 Only one of them need to be successful. So I think neither of them need to reach the threshold.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of the threshold?

Comment: @Shiloh_C why do you think there should be a greedy algorithm? This looks like some sort of unbounded knapsack problem with a special objective function.

Comment: @algrid I think you are right. I have figure out a knapsack algorithm. It seems not very bad.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use an algorithm similar to fractional knapsack, but with a twist:

First, temporarily set any success rates of nodes with a success rate higher than the boundary to the value of the boundary.
For example, if the boundary was 90% and Node C was (100%, $5), Node C would become (90% success rate, $5).

This is because you are looking for the minimum cost to meet a boundary. So for example if your boundary is 50%, you would still want to choose the node with (50% success rate, $5) over a node with (100% success rate, $6). So your node with 100% success rate might as well be 50% success rate

Then, sort the nodes by ascending success rate / cost.

Each step of the algorithm would be to add the node with the lowest success rate / cost to your solution list of nodes until the total success rate of the nodes reaches the boundary. However, an added step would be if the added node creates a total success rate greater than the boundary, you would have to go through your solution list of nodes from the greatest success rate / cost to the lowest and see if removing that node will still maintain reaching the percent boundary. You would continue removing possible nodes until no nodes can be removed and the boundary is still satisfied.

For example: if your list had nodes as added in order:

(20%, $2), (30%, $1), (40%, .5$) and the boundary was 70%,

the total percent is 90% at the moment which is greater than 70%. 
Since node (40%, .5$) was just added, you look at node (30%, $1) only to find it cannot be removed because then the boundary would be 60% which is less than the boundary.
Then you look at the next node (20%, $2) which can be removed since the remaining total percent would be 70% which meets the required boundary. You would keep going down the line, but in this example, the newly altered (30%, $1), (40%, .5$) would be valid as the solution.